# Embed a Contour board in an iframe in Object Explorer or Slate

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

In Foundry, how can I embed a Contour board in an iframe in Object Explorer or Slate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `analysisRid`, the `refRid` and the `nodeId` for the board you want and plug it into this url structure:

```
https://{WORKSPACE_HOST}/workspace/contour-app/{analysisRid}/ref/{refRid}/node/{nodeId}
```

You can then optionally include `?embedded=true` at the end of the URL to remove the workspace bar, which results in a frame that only includes the board. It is also recommended to include `&useMostRecentNodeId=true` so your embed will render even after the Contour path is edited.